# Input validation, expect error on null input

Tags: applescript, dialog

I expect the code to display an error and then ask the question again when the user enters no text

```
set tname to ""
repeat while tname is equal to ""
    set tname to text returned of (display dialog ¬
        "Hello" buttons {"next"} ¬
        default button 1 default answer "")
end repeat
if tname is equal to "" then display dialog "error"
```

Comment: Can you add some details to the question so it doesn't just consist of a block of code without context? What does work, what doesn't? What have you tried to solve the problem already?

Comment: Please don't just edit the title, edit the question text itself to add details. What doesn't work right now?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if tname is equal to "" then display dialog "error"
```

is never reached while tname is empty. You need to put it inside the loop.